# Heroku Deployment of node js

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, node-modules

So I am trying to deploy a discord bot through heroku but am having issues with the deployment.. everything works fine when I run my bot locally but when trying to deploy to heroku I get this:

---

> 2020-03-21T18:08:07.914594+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:08.476878+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.286392+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215281+00:00 app[worker.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215306+00:00 app[worker.1]:     throw err;
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215307+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ^
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215307+00:00 app[worker.1]:
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215307+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'enmap'
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215308+00:00 app[worker.1]: Require stack:
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215308+00:00 app[worker.1]: - /app/index.js
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215323+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215324+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215329+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215330+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215330+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object. (/app/index.js:4:15)
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215330+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215331+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215331+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215331+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215331+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10) {
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215337+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215337+00:00 app[worker.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.215337+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
>
> 2020-03-21T18:08:10.270170+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1

---

I have followed steps found at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies. but still getting error.. the app log is saying the app is deployed but the bot is not coming online. I don't know what to do at this point. Any help or point to any article would be greatly helpful.

my package.json is here >

```
{
    "name": "botname",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "botname Discord Server Bot",
    "main": "index.js",
    "start": "node .",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "Skemicle",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "discord.js": "^11.5.1"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "12.14.1",
        "npm": "6.13.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: have you run npm install before starting the server?

Comment: i ran npm install before doing anything with my code yes

Comment: can you add your `package.json` code?

Comment: package code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"dependencies": {
   "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
   "enmap": "^5.2.4"
},
```

you have to add `enmap` to dependencies and if you are using other npm libraries you have to add that to dependencies also because heroku installs dependencies via `npm install` and that downloads packages listed in `package.json` -> `dependencies`.

Comment: Thank you.. also needed to add "better-sqlite3": "^6.0.1" to dependencies as well =)
Bot is now online and functioning thank you for saving me.